# Erro ao remover item pilha

Tags: c, stack

Qual o erro da função `pop`??

```c
void pop(Pilha *pilha){
  if(pilha->size == 0){
    puts("pilha vazia");
  } else {
    printf("item removido: %d\n\n", pilha->itens[--pilha->size]);
    free(pilha->itens[--pilha->size]);
  }
}
```

Link da [Pilha](https://gist.github.com/EliveltonCristiano/9242703).

Answer (score 5):

Você decrementa o valor de `pilha->size` duas vezes. O certo é fazê-lo apenas uma vez.

Answer (score -3):

O tamanho da pilha é decrementado mais de uma vez por loop. Lembre que `--` muda realmente o valor da variável.

```
void pop(Pilha *pilha){
  if(pilha->size == 0){
    puts("pilha vazia");
  } else {
    printf("item removido: %d\n\n", pilha->itens[--pilha->size]);
    free(pilha->itens[pilha->size]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente esse código dará problema de execução na segunda retirada...